# mysqli_query SELECT FROM WHERE [ partial match ]?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that a time filed that is stored in this format "2010.06.04. | 18:53 01".
What I need is to select rows that have a specific date, for example "2010.06.04."

Right now I am doing it my first selecting all rows and then looping through them and adding ones with the specified date to a new array.

Maybe there is an easier way to do it and I somehow can select it using `mysqli_query`?

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, you may want to change the column to a DATETIME. You could then use the BETWEEN keyword.

Comment: Never seen a timestamp like that before! You're losing out on a lot of nice functions that would get if you used a datetime field. But perhaps your app was already locked into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you will need is a `like` query (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_field` LIKE '2010.06.04%'
```

**Note** The % is a wildcard that states any text can go here.

I would also consider switching that field to be DATETIME field, this would allow you to do alot more with the data. - **Note** be careful when doing this, I would recommend creating another field first then calculating the proper value. You can then drop the unwanted field.

Answer (score 1):

The LIKE keyword....

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

SELECT * FROM .... WHERE date LIKE '2010.06.04%'

Answer (score 1):

Three cheers for not using the DATE and DATETIME field types.

```
WHERE time_field LIKE "2010.06.04 %"
```